# How to initialize an int pointer inside a struct assingning it to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've got a struct to say:

```
struct mystruct {
       int *myarray;
}
```

In my main function, I want to assign to "myarray" the values of a predefined array.

```
int main(){
   int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   //how to "assign" array values to myarray ?;
}
```

I would like avoid making a cycle of an assignment like :

```
struct mystruct str = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
for(int i = 0;i<size_of_array;i++){
    str->myarray[i] = array[i];
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: You don't have an array inside a struct. You have a pointer inside a struct.

Comment: yes,it's true .

Comment: Is what possible? Assign a pointer to point at an array? Yes it is possible, as explained in the chapter about pointers in your C programming book. Make a hardcopy of an array? Yes it is possible, but you have to use malloc + memcpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `memcpy`

```
struct->array = malloc(sizeof(some_array));
memcpy(struct->array, some_array, sizeof(some_array));
```

and for your case this is

```
   str->array = malloc(sizeof(array));
   memcpy(str->array, array, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: The structure `str` doesn't contain memory for the data, only a pointer (=address of the data). Before using `memcpy` you would have to allocate memory for the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct mystruct {
       int *myarray;
}
```

here `myarray` is just a pointer to memory. There is no space reserved there, so your example will fail.

You have two options:

1. Just use the array you already have, this assumes the array is not free'd before the structure is free'd:

   `instance->myarray = array;`
2. reserve memory and memcpy the data

   ```
   instance->myarray = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
   memcpy(instance->myarray, array, sizeof(int) * 5);
   ```

Comment: And the `array` should not be modified later, e.g. to create a second instance of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
typedef struct test
{
    int i;
    char c[2][5];
} test;
```

This can be initialized using:

```
test t = {10, {{'a','b','c','d','\0'}, { 0 }}};
// or
test t = {10, {{'a','b','c','d','\0'}, {'x','y','z','v','\0'}}};
```

Comment: Please (a) don't include line numbers in code, and (b) format code as code (indent 4 spaces or use the "{}" icon). Thanks.

Comment: You can also format code by highlighting it and pressing `Ctrl`+`k`

Comment: This does not really answer the question because the in the questions example code the structure instance is dynamically allocated.